# Using a formula for conditional summing in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with 3 columns.  Column A is a vendor number and contains duplicates.  Column B is an invoice type which contains duplicates.  Column C is an invoice amount.  For every vendor in column A, I want a sum of all the amounts in column C for each invoice type in column B.

Comment: Copy Column A and B to another column then use Remove Duplicates on the Data tab to get a unique list.  Then use SUMIFS()

Answer (score 0):

Place the following formula in Cell D2 and copy it down.

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,A2,B:B,B2)
```

Check and let us know if it works.